# How to keep the aspect ratio of a UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, aspect-ratio

Does anyone have an idea how to keep the Height/Width Ratio 1:1 of a UserControl?

E.g. if Height > Width, Width & Height will have the same size and vice versa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure this will work, but if you register a handler for the [`SizeChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged.aspx) event and in there put in your code keep the aspect ratio 1:1.

The [`SizeChangedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.sizechangedeventargs.aspx) argument has the old size and the new size so you can check which has changed and update the other accordingly.

You might need to introduce a guard variable so that you don't get a cascade of `SizeChanged` events as a result of updating the `Height` or `Width`.

Comment: I think control will be blinking when resizing.

Comment: It will not blink because WPF uses retained mode and rendering is done at a lower priority, so rendering will see the final result of all the `SizeChanged` events.  Exception:  If your Window is `SizeToContent` and its size is affected, `SetWindowPos()` is called immediately during the calculations so you probably will see something.

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative:

```
<local:MyControl Width="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me and seems like the simplest answer (although I don't really understand what it's doing).

Comment: @brianberns it is binding the `Width` property to the `ActualHeight` property. But the `ActualHeight` of what? Of a RelativeSource! And _what_ relative source? (it)Self! That is, I'm saying that "I want my own Width to be whatever ActualHeight the layout system calculated for me".

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. BTW, I found a problem with this solution:  If only the width of the main window changes (e.g. by dragging its right border in or out), the control does not know to resize, because its height has not changed.

Answer (score 6):

Try using a ViewBox and setting its Stretch property to Uniform

Comment: Unlike some other published solution, this ones even works when required height/width ratio is different from 1:1

Answer (score 0):

i used this code for keeping aspect ratio

inside usercontrol globally define org_width, org_height, org_ratio :

```
private static double org_width = 77.6;//desired width
private static double org_height = 81.4;//desired height

private static double org_ratio = org_width / org_height;
```

use this code inside usercontrol in SizeChanged event:

```
FrameworkElement UCborder = this;
UCborder.Width = UCborder.Height*org_ratio;
```

and finally your user control code should looks like this:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace yournamespace
{
    public partial class YourUserControl : UserControl
    {

      private static double org_width = 77.6;//desired width
      private static double org_height = 81.4;//desired height

     private static double org_ratio = org_width / org_height; // width/height



     public YourUserControl()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }


     private void UserControl_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
     {
          FrameworkElement UCborder = this;
          UCborder.Width = UCborder.Height*org_ratio;
     }
  }
}
```

good luck

Answer (score -2):

```
private bool isSizeChangeDefered;

 private void uiElement_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         //Keep Acpect Ratio
        const double factor = 1.8;
        if(isSizeChangeDefered)
            return;

        isSizeChangeDefered = true;
        try
        {
            if (e.WidthChanged)
            {
                driverPan.Height = e.NewSize.Width * factor; 
            }
            if (e.HeightChanged)
            {
                driverPan.Height = e.NewSize.Width / factor; 
            }
        }
        finally
        {
        //    e.Handled = true;
            isSizeChangeDefered = false;
        }
    }
```

maybe this helps... cheers

Comment: This answer is basically an example of the answer provided by ChrisF 18 months ago. It also seems incomplete (what is the driverPan variable?) and I believe it has a logic issue if both height/width are changed in the same event (resize diagonal)